# Simplifying css coding issues

Tags: css

When I look at WordPress coding as well as other sites.  I mainly see a while lot of scripts and css styles that it drives me bonkers.  Here is evidence of what I am getting at:

Ul.nav setup

```
  ul {
     /* some css */
 }
 ul.nav {
     /* some css */
 }
 /* and the rest goes on about ul nav and hover events */
```

Vs simple css (in my honest opinion)

```
 .nav {
     /* some css */
 }
 .nav:hover {
     /* some css */
 }
```

What will the difference be in these methods and are they the correct format of css writing?   And if it is possible.  Why isn't every code simple and concise to load faster etc?  How it's done on both versions are correct to make a link work. (To be assumed)

Thank you all for taking your time to help!

Comment: The only difference is that the first code snippet will only apply to `<ul>` elements with the class `nav`. The second snippet will apply to any element with the class `nav`. **Both are syntactically correct CSS**. The first version is of course, more specific, and accounts for the possibility that there are *other* elements with the `nav` class.

Comment: Your two example rules are not equivalent so your question is unclear. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The concise and effectiveness between both examples. @j08691  I seen so many sites use way too much coding and thought about trying to make it simple so it's more effective.  But wondered if it was the right approach

Comment: It's always the right approach to make it simple and concise, but your two examples aren't equivalent or simplified versions of one another.

Comment: How so j08691?  I mean can you shed some light so I can understand?

Comment: Shed some light on what? I really don't understand what your core question is.

Comment: @GarethCompton in the first example, you're referencing an element and a class. Those 2 rules have different specificity and just target a ul. In the second example, you're referencing a class and a class with a hover pseudo class - one references whatever `.nav` is and the other is referencing a pseudo class. They aren't comparable examples of code. I'm assuming your question is just basically "why refer to an element in one instance and a class in another, when you could just always reference the class instead?" or something like that?

Comment: Bout right.  Not always great especially with my english.  Tried to make both examples the nav menu where one is the traditional w3schools.com way and simplified way

Comment: Okay to clarify.  The first example was a cut of the full example.  It would continue to ul.nav li then ul.nav li:hover.   It was in the css note code that I mentioned it was going to go into description of hover ul nav li example vs the .nav and .nav: hover example

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you can add style to everything in the ul tags, and everything in the ul tags with a class of nav. In the second example you are adding style to anything with the class nav, and anything with the class nav when someone hovers their mouse over the nav. If that makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you chose as evidence probably is somebody specifically naming their elements `.nav`

For me, it's better to have more specific classnames, but not too long. But then we're going into the hardest job in IT "naming things".

Giving your `ul` or `nav` the classname .nav is a bit redundant. So i disagree with your assessment there that it's simpler. If you have a vertical nav and a horizontal nav, then .nav would be more complicated to style.

It really depends on the project, the scope and the readability.

Answer (score 0):

CSS validators frown at the first example (overqualified elements) , but for the records
ul.nav will inherit everything from the class of .nav.